# Sublime Text 3, Using syntax parse of JS with autocompletion of TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text 3

I want to use syntax theme of JS with Autocmpletion of TS.

This is JS syntax and i like it, it's provide better keys definition to use in themes.
[image]

TS syntax for example doesn't provide variable key in theme map to apply styles for it.
[image]

But when i'm using JS syntax parse which i like, i can't use this cool helpers of TS syntax.
[image]

How can i use syntax of JS with autocompletion helpers of TS at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

> How can i use syntax of JS with autocompletion helpers of TS at the same time?

You will have to fork the plugin. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin

## Warning

JS Syntax is a **subset** of TS so you cannot just use the JS grammar for TS blindly.